# How to handle a big5 personality traits task

Tags: python, regression, classification, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset consists of N tweets annotated with the big 5 personality traits (`extroverted`, `stable`, `agreeable`, `conscientious`, and `open`). Each category represented by a real number.

I want to predict the score of each personality trait for the documents, but I don't know how should I handle the task.

One possibility is to split it into 5 different regression tasks, but then a classifier could miss the correlations between the 5 classes (e.g. a document written by someone `extroverted` has a higher probability that the author is also `open`).

Another one is to apply a multi-label approach, but I don't think that is possible since this way is applied when there are labels and not real values (classification instead of regression), no?

Comment: Are you trying to predict the personality traits or get some score associted with them?

Comment: to get the score.

Comment: This is, my friend, a statistical question rather than a programming question. I would say it belongs on a place like Cross Validated.

Comment: You're right, I'll close it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn have it, read it here: https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/multiclass.html

"**Multilabel classification** assigns to each sample a set of target labels. This can be thought as predicting properties of a data-point that are not mutually exclusive, such as topics that are relevant for a document. A text might be about any of religion, politics, finance or education at the same time or none of these."

```
Support multilabel:
sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier
sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV
```

Or may be you need this:

"**Multioutput regression** assigns each sample a set of target values. This can be thought of as predicting several properties for each data-point, such as wind direction and magnitude at a certain location."

```
Support multiclass-multioutput:
sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier
```

Comment: but I don't have labels!, I have a real value for each trait, is it possible?

Comment: May be I don't got it right. I added "Multioutput regression" part to my answer

Comment: Thanks, what i read in the documentary is: `This is a simple strategy for extending regressors that do not natively support multi-target regression`. Thus, what are the ones that support multi-target regression?

Comment: @Ghanem I think you are talking about MultiOutputRegressor, am I right? "Multioutput regression support can be added to any regressor with MultiOutputRegressor." But as I far as I understand, RandomForestClassifier/RandomForestRegressor can be trained on multioutput data as is, for example.